Modelling an eddy current sensor
An eddy current sensor is modeled as an air core transformer with shorted secondary:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
According to Kirchoff's laws, the total voltages around the loops are given by:

The equivalent impedance on the primary side is given by the following equation where M is the mutual inductance:

Can someone explain how we arrive at this equation?
Update:

I2 is contrary direction.
First equation: correct: \$ + j * omega * M * I2 \$
Second equation: correct: \$ + j * omega * M * I1 \$


Try solving it first

You have made some errors ... https://i.sstatic.net/8SzVxbTK.png

Link to "modelling" ...
With the new update ...
If you solve the two equations now, you should have the results you are searching.
Straightforward.

t1 and t2 are what you are searching for, just rewrite as you want.
Simulated with microcap v12.
Presented Zin = f(frequency) -> Phase (Zin) .vs. abs(Zin)  (kc parameter).


Huh, how does the plot show a complex pole/zero with no capacitors shown?

Parameter kc seems to be the key (?).

Well, yeah that's showing the sensitivity, but can you explain why it looks like that? Ohhh, also it's phase, I see, but that's not what I get from simulating the same (I think) thing: https://i.sstatic.net/GiaWy3QE.png https://i.sstatic.net/nSuve7vP.png

@TimWilliams ... Is kc varying from 0.9 to 1? It is not "frequency" with axis x. It is the module of "input impedance" ... Although, you are right if it is "frequency" (confirmed).

Module? Modulo what--? Oh, magnitude? Ohh, so it's a-- well, it's not a polar graph because it's, not, but it's plotting magnitude against angle. That's... very strange.

Yes ... "Magnitude" in place of "module". I tried this "representation" for getting the best "view" of "input impedance" ... You can change the value of resistors ... inductors ... kc ... and see immediately what happens. For verifying, just make kc=1 (ideal transformer) and you will see the values of input impedances when the frequency is low ... and when it is high ...
